# Windows 10 - Set Start Layout via GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I could really use some help with this.

Following the official instructions on [technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt431718%28v=vs.85%29), I am trying to deploy a start menu to my windows 10 machines.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected, the start menu is not changing for the user. It is locked, though, which just means that the GPO was actually applied, and I could confirm this using GPRESULT.

Furthermore, I checked the registry, the two registry values

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\LockedStartLayout  DWORD 1
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\StartLayoutFile String \\domain.local\share\pathtoxml.xml
```

are set correctly.

The xml file is on a file share, I reference it using the UNC path in the GPO. The "domain users" group has read access to the file. I verified that from a user account.

What else could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the answer I initially accepted is wrong.

I can confirm that it is perfectly possible to distribute the StartLayout via GPO to Windows 10 Professional, too. It works for both the computer configuration as well as the user configuration GPO.

The problem in my specific case lay elsewhere. I had both a permission problem on the share of the xml file and, apparently, a corrupted xml file. The event viewer messages were not helping to figure this out.

After sorting out the permission issues and recreating the xml file, everything works the way I expected it to.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have all the basic troubleshooting steps complete. Some points that are easily missed:

- Are you running Windows 10 **Enterprise**? Start layout control is not supported in Windows 10 Pro.
- Is the target system the same architecture as the system you exported the layout from? Start layout can only be applied to a device using the same architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) as the device on which Start layout was created.

If neither of those is an issue, for testing purposes, copy the XML file onto a target system, and change the path to point to it locally, just to rule out any possible strange network issues.

Also, try manually importing the layout to a target system using the `Import-StartLayout` PowerShell script. This would rule out any issues with the XML file

Finally, check it the source and target machines running the same version/build of Windows 10, with the same updates. Although not explicitly stated anywhere, it wouldn't be the first time Microsoft has failed to ensure backward compatibility with an update.

EDIT: Confirmation on the lack of Windows 10 Pro compatibility is given [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare) under the section entitled "Existing Fundamentals":

[image]

**EDIT #2:** With the newest release of Windows 10 Pro (version 1703) it is now possible to deploy a customized start layout via GPO (only to W10 systems running v1703, though). See: [What's new in Windows 10 1703](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1703)

> Enterprises have been able to apply customized Start and taskbar layouts to devices running Windows 10 Enterprise and Education. In Windows 10, version 1703, customized Start and taskbar layout can also be applied to Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I have checked all this. Identical machines, same versions and updates, xml via unc file share and mapped drive. Can you elaborate on import-startlayout? I thought that only works on a wmi file, and only on the default user. As for the version, no, I have Pro. From the linked technet page: _In Windows 10 Pro, Windows 10 Enterprise, and Windows 10 Education, you can use a Group Policy Object (GPO) to deploy a customized Start layout to users in a domain._ Though I admit that a few paragraphs later they just change the wording.

Comment: @vic The version is why it's not working. In the TechNet article, it **explicitly** states **"Start layout control is not supported in Windows 10 Pro."**

Comment: To elaborate, it looks like the first mention is just a screw-up on Microsoft's part. This kind of feature segmentation is extremely common. Remember that the vast majority of Pro customers are still non-domain *consumers* who would have no need for such features.

Comment: So you are absolutely sure about that? Because I did find some forum entries where there were voices saying Pro is supported. Anyway, let's assume for the moment it really doesn't work with Pro: how am I supposed to know which administrative template or policy will work with pro and which one won't? Can you point me to a list that will confirm the information in a less ambiguous way?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, just saying that I encounter this scenario frequently. This is what they refer generally to as "Advanced Granular UX control", and you can see where it falls in the comparison chart here: https://goo.gl/B7ayMX. Microsoft assumes that most business users large enough need Group Policy are running Enterprise. You could certainly call your volume licensing vendor for clarification - I'm sure they'd be able to provide confirmation from their Microsoft reps. There's no definitive list I'm aware of, though many policies have a "Supported On" box that is somewhat accurate.

Comment: And I take it back...I missed it in the above link. Expand "Existing fundamentals" and see that "Start Screen Control with Group Policy" does not have a check under Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Mind you, start screen and start menu layout are two very different things. I am not trying to change the start screen.

Comment: Well, I can only point you to content that's available online, and TechNet documentation is the most official source there is. If that isn't enough for you, your next step is to call your vendor or call Microsoft if you have a support contract. Post back and let us know what you find, but I would be willing to bet it's only supported in Enterprise.

Comment: Now I have to take my comment back. Microsoft seems to use the terms _start screen_, _start layout_, and _start menu layout_ interchangeably. So this really must be the answer then. Or, as you say, at least what can be confirmed on the net. A relief, and a kick in the 'nads at the same time. :) Why, Microsoft..why? Anyway, thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: No problem! I do a lot of work with Group Policy customization, and I run into this kind of thing all the time. We have half Pro/half Enterprise clients, so it's a never-ending battle trying to figure out what will and won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a start screen without this gpo with some limitations mainly that you can only configure it once during the production of a standard syspreped image.

When creating the image setup your start screen as you would like it then shutdown and boot from a usb key. When you are booted from another os you can copy the `TileDataLayer folder` from `c:\users\you\appdata\local\` to `c:\users\default\appdata\local\`

When this is done all new user accounts created using this image will have the preconfigured start screen regardless of their edition.

This has the added benefit over enterprise edition + the gpo in that users can pin new items to the menu.